# elasticsearch - delete by query plugin, how to delete all records with date_time before today?

Tags: elasticsearch

Following delete by query plugin [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.0/plugins-delete-by-query.html) I have managed to delete records from my elasticseatch server with this simple query:

```
{
 "query": {
    "term": {
      "field1": "value1"
    } 
  }
}
```

Now, I have field date_time. What I would like to achieve is to delete all records which have date_time value before today (date_time < today ). There is no information in the docs about more complex delete queries. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a [`range` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) and some [date math](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#date-math) like this:

```
{
 "query": {
    "range": {
      "date_time": {
        "lt" : "now/d"
      } 
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: "type": "number_format_exception",
        "reason": "For input string: \"now/d\""

Comment: Can you share the mapping of your `date_time` field? Looks like it's not a date but a timestamp in milliseconds?

Comment: Can you update your question with what you get from `curl -XGET localhost:9200/your_index`?

Comment: "date_time": {
            "type": "long"
          },